# How do I setup 4 channel surround sound with 2 stereo speakers on voicemeeter in Windows 10 somehow?

Tags: audio

I would like to use 2 stereo speakers in Windows 10 (voicemeeter) to have 4 channels of audio (Front left; Front right; Rear left; Rear right). In Windows there is an option to setup Quadraphonic sound if you right click on VoiceMeeter Input option in the sound settings (under playback) from control panel and then click "configure speakers."

If I can route my 2 stereo speakers as 4 channels in voicemeeter then hopefully I can configure voicemeeter input as quadraphonic in sound settings because windows will recognize the playback device as having 4 channels. And this way I could play movies and games with surround sound in quadraphonic. Can voicemeeter split 2 stereo speakers into 4 mono channels for quadraphonic sound (if that is how it would even work?)

[quadraphonic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GULbj.png)

Comment: How many ***actual*** speakers are you using?